# EVP_DigestUpdate and "invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’"

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, sha256

Here's the example taken from [EVP Message Digests](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests) on the OpenSSL wiki:

```
void digest_message(unsigned char *message, unsigned char **digest, unsigned int *digest_len)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

    if((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))
        handleErrors();

    if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digest, digest_len))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
}
```

The problem is when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
evp_test.cpp:18:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
 if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))

In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstring:42:0
```

So `strlen` being called on message causes the error because `strlen` expects a `const char`? Is this because strings are arrays of `const chars`?

What should I be doing differently to solve the issue?

Comment: Lol... we were just talking about C++ compiler support for OpenSSL. See [Compile errors when compiling with C++ compiler](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2016-March/006353.html). The consensus is to not support C++ compilers "just because". As far as I know, there are no technical reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed:

```
void digest_message(const unsigned char *message, size_t message_len,
                    unsigned char **digest, unsigned int *digest_len)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

    if((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, message_len))
        handleErrors();

    if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digest, digest_len))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
}
```

You were right that `strlen` needs an array of `char`, and not an `unsigned char` or `byte`.

The bigger problem was the design/engineering. An explicit length parameter was needed because there's no guarantee a byte array is NULL terminated like a C-string. In fact, a byte array might have a few NULLs embedded in it.